# Make with debug returning that file not exists

Tags: makefile

When run make in debug mode I get issues with `File does not exist.`:

```
GNU Make 3.81

This program built for i386-apple-darwin11.3.0
Reading makefiles...
Updating goal targets....
 File `compose/up' does not exist.
Must remake target `compose/up'.
docker network create --subnet= workbench || true
Error response from daemon: network with name workbench already exists
docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml up -d
Successfully remade target file `compose/up'.`enter code here`
```

Take a look at my `Makefile`:

```
SHELL := /bin/sh

.DEFAULT_GOAL := compose/up
.PHONY: compose/up

compose/up:
    docker network create --subnet=${DOCKER_NETWORK_SUBNET} workbench || true
    docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml up -d $(service)
```

What I am missing in the make configuration?

Comment: I don't understand.  What's the problem here?  It seems to be working (your commands are being run).  The "does not exist" message is part of make's debug output, telling you which targets exist and which are out of date.  If you don't want to see make's debugging output then don't add the `-d` option to the make command line.

Comment: @MadScientist I understand now, it's not a issue right. Thanks.